# Can't insert encrypted data?

Tags: sql-server, encryption, sql-insert

I'm trying to insert encrypted data into my SQL Server table. First step, I created a master key, a certificate and a private key:

```
CREATE MASTER KEY
ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'PASSWORD@123'
GO

CREATE CERTIFICATE ElipseCert
ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'SENHA@123'
WITH SUBJECT = 'Certificado Senha Usuario'
GO

CREATE SYMMETRIC KEY KeyElipse
WITH ALGORITHM = AES_256
ENCRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE ElipseCert 
GO
```

After I tried to insert data:

```
OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY KeyElipse
DECRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE ElipseCert

DECLARE @GUID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER = (SELECT KEY_GUID('KeyElipse'))
INSERT INTO Usuario VALUES ('FONSECA', ENCRYPTBYKEY(@GUID, 'Abcd1234'))
GO

SELECT * FROM Usuario

CLOSE SYMMETRIC KEY KeyElipse
```

But when I executed the code returns me:

> The certificate has a private key that is protected by a user defined password. That password needs to be provided to enable the use of the private key.

What's wrong?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

> The certificate has a private key that is protected by a user defined password. That password needs to be provided to enable the use of the private key

So provide the password, replace this code

```
OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY KeyElipse
DECRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE ElipseCert
```

with this one

```
OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY KeyElipse
DECRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE ElipseCert WITH PASSWORD = 'SENHA@123';
```